# Odd behaviour using flexible array member

Tags: c, malloc, c99, flexible-array-member

I tried to replace a void* member of a struct with a flexible array member using the more accepted idiom:

```
typedef struct Entry {
    int counter;
    //void* block2; // This used to be what I had
    unsigned char block[1];
}
```

I then add entries into a continuous memory block:

```
void *memPtr = mmap(NULL, someSize*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
                        MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

as such:

```
int number = 0;

int AddEntry(void *data) {
   Entry *entry;
   entry = malloc(sizeof(Entry) + ((SECTOR_SIZE-1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
   entry->counter = 1;
   memcpy(entry->block, data, SECTOR_SIZE);

   // make sure number doesn't overflow space, etc...
   memcpy(&memPtr[number], entry, sizeof(Entry) + ((SECTOR_SIZE-1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
   number++;
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is unpacking this data once I need it. For example, if I do:

```
void * returnBlock(int i) {
    Entry * entry  = &memPtr[i];
    printf("Entry counter is %d\n", entry->counter); // returns 1, reliably
    return entry->block; // Gives me gibberish but not if I uncomment void* block2.
}
```

Is there a reason this could be? I don't necessarily think I'm stomping on stuff anywhere, and it used to work with the void* approach. **The weird thing is that if I put a dummy void* back into the struct, it works**. It doesn't work if I put in a dummy int.

Edit: actually, it also fails if `number` in `AddEntry` is not 0. What am I stepping on, if anything?

Comment: You cannot make an array of a structure that contains a flexible array member.

Comment: What is `memptr[i]` exactly? You cannot subscript a `void` pointer.

Comment: As @R.. says, it makes no sense to have an array of flexible arrays. All the idea of flexible array members is that you have the "header" part of the data structure and the array itself contiguous. So if you really need your `Entry`s of different size, you'd need an array of pointers to that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
&memPtr[number]
```

Since `memPtr` is a `void *` pointer, this isn't actually allowed in C at all.  Some compilers do allow arithmetic on `void *` pointers as a language extension - however they treat it as if it were a `char *` pointer.

That means that `&memPtr[number]` is likely indexing only `number` *bytes* into your memory block - so the second `Entry` structure copied in will overlap the first one, and so on.

Your allocation line appears to be assuming 1024 bytes per `Entry` (if `someSize` is a number of `Entry` structures), so you probably want something like:

```
((char *)memPtr + number * 1024)
```

(and similar in the `returnBlock()` function).

However, if you do this you will notice that there is no point in using the flexible array member - because you're creating a contiguous array of these structures, and don't have a separate index, you have to assume each one is a fixed size.  This means that you might as well make each one a fixed size:

```
typedef struct Entry {
    int counter;
    unsigned char block[1024 - sizeof counter];
}
```